# Password Encryption Using opencart database for sitewide login

Tags: php, encryption, opencart

Hello hopefully I can be pointed in the right direction and gain some clarity as I am now confused.

I have a website that also has opencart (Version 1.5.6.1) attached the two are styled to look the same. I have come to a point where I need users to log into services on MY website however I do not really want a user to create two sets of data, one for the shop and another for my services. I have done research and found I can just add info into the opencart database rather than having two independent databases.

All was going well until I came to password encryption, opencart (apparently) uses "salt sha1" Encryption

Where as the tools I am using on the website have this code (md5 encryption):

```
$crypt_pwd = md5($password);
```

I know I am asking relatively stupid questions here but how would I add into my website code support for the same encryption? Even just a pointer in the right direction would be helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Opencart supports both schemes so you should be fine just using the `md5` hashed password in the customer table.  In this case you can simply leave the salt blank.

As a point of reference, take a look at this query used in the `login()` method in `system/library/customer.php` which is where the login is validated:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($email)) . "' 
    AND
    (
        password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "')))))
        OR password = '" . $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "'
    )
    AND status = '1'
    AND approved = '1'
```

Notice that the database field is matched against either SHA1 with salt OR md5 hashed versions.

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer, one problem down with your answer however, I have been playing with this all day to no avail, I still have a problem :S (I am no means a programmer) 

If I create a login on my side of the website I can log into opencart with the same information, However if I create a login using opencart it "salts" it and I cannot log into my side of the site with that users details.

I have tried adding 

    or $crypt_pwd = SHA1($password); 

That did nothing :( I dont think I actually understand this salt thing and where it gets its values from :s Sorry lol

Comment: My suggestion would be to either amend the opencart insert to strictly use `md5` hash and/or redirect traffic so that all registration takes place on a single page.  Take a look at `/catalog/model/account/customer.php` - specifically the `addCustomer()` and `editPassword()` methods.  There you can change query to something like `password = '" . $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "'` and `salt = ''`.  Hope that makes sense to you.

Answer (score -2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

```
$encrypted = sha($passphrase);
//or 
$salt = "my secret salt ASF8908sjQ@Te8u";
$encrypted = sha($salt . $passphrase);
```